# Convert math-heavy epub to mobi?

Tags: kindle, epub, calibre, conversion, mobi

I have an epub with a lot of equations, and these get garbled when converted to mobi using calibre. (E.g., “=“ gets dropped off in the mobi version.)

They also become rather small images. (I’d prefer them as bigger images.)

Comment: Does converting to AZW3 work any better for you?

Comment: @user10216038 I haven’t tried because it doesn’t work with send-to-email. But I have seen good azw math textbooks.

Comment: check if `kindlegen` makes any difference